# Migration From ASM to ARM Load Balancer

Tags: azure, migration, azure-resource-manager

I am working through migrating the last of my ASM resources to ARM and the only concern I have is the load balanced set. The current configuration has a endpoints under the load balanced set. Currently, ASM to ARM migration doesn't support endpoints with an ACL associated to it. What are the best options to migrate? My thought would be to remove the endpoints from the load balancer and allow that endpoint to be open and then control the traffic at a VM level with a classic NSG, which is supported during migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Endpoint ACLs are [not supported features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview#unsupported-features) when you migrate from ASM to ARM. So you have to remove the ACL first. Instead of endpoint ACL, ARM resources use NSG to control the network inbound and outbound traffic based on a set of rules. There are subnet level NSG and NIC level NSG in ARM.

> You can specify network ACLs for **endpoints** only. You can't specify
>   an ACL for a virtual network or a specific subnet contained in a
>   virtual network. It is recommended to use network security groups
>   (NSGs) instead of ACLs, whenever possible. When using NSGs, endpoint
>   access control list will be **replaced and no longer enforced**. To learn
>   more about NSGs, see [Network security group overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview)

Comment: I'm very aware of the MS answer for the migration, but didn't know if there was an easier way to handle the transition without causing the down time associated with migrating without endpoints attached.

Comment: MS migration is recommended and easy way to do a migration. In this case, you still could access the VM via the load balancer associated public IP address once migration if you have a load balanced set. If no NSG set, by default, you could access the windows VM via RDP port 3389. Afterward, you could attach an NSG for the subnet level or NIC level.

Comment: Thanks @NancyXiong. Exactly the direction I was going in, appreciate the confirmation.